# webform submission form altering in drupal 7

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I would like to ask a conceptual/architectural question about drupal 7 webform. I have different webforms and submissions of that, I would like to add a textfield to the submissions, so it will allow admin user to write a comment about the submission form and it will send an email to user who submitted that form when admin user saves that comment. Along with that feature I want submission form to update itself with this new comment.

I know I will have to create a custom module to alter the form and I don't need all the codes that is going to solve the issue. I just need a pathway or an architecture that is going to lead me to the solution.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: There is already a module which does similar/part of functionality which you're trying to achieve, [Webform Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_webform_comments) Module. You might need to check if the module has rules support or provides custom action which can be used to sent an email to users.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can also have a look at [Webform Revisions](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_revisions) Module, if this suite your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh. I will take a look at it and see if it suites.

Comment: @Yogesh- I downloaded and enabled the Webform Comments module but it didn't add anything on the submission page. There is not much info about this module, do i need to do any additional set up?

Comment: I've not used module my-self so won't be able to tell exact steps for using the module. But The module defines 2 blocks, you might need to check if those are properly configured to display on submission page or not.